# How to optimize UPDATE with a nested SELECT subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, subquery

I wrote a complicated UPDATE query, and it works, but it looks menacing.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

In each topic user 'Bob123' posted anonymously.  When you post anonymously in a topic, you get a unique anonymous index for that topic.

Say I want to merge two topics together.  Bob123 has a different anon index in both topics, so his unique anon index wouldn't be unique.  I only have two pieces of data to work with: $topic_id, the topic id you are merging into, and $post_id_list, all the post ids that got merged over.

I want to update all anonymous_index entries per each distinct poster_id's post in that topic.  This anonymous_index needs to be the original index they had in the topic before the other topic was merged into it.

The first SELECT query first selects the anon indices of the moved posts.
The outer SELECT query gets the first non-merged post's anon index (if it is `> 0`) of those merged posters in the topic and selects a merged anon index from the first query.

Then, I update it.  Wherever the anon index of those posters in that topic doesn't equal the old index, I update it.

Is there something simple that I'm missing here?  I don't like the fact that I have a subquery in a subquery.

At first I was using `HAVING MIN(anonymous_index) <> MAX(anonymous_index)` along with `AND post_id NOT IN ($merged_post_list)`to select the poster id list that needed to be updated and an unmerged anon index, but it returned 0 rows with this.  If the merged post is BEFORE all original posts (and has a larger anon index), then the minimum anon index will match the maximum index for that poster.  So making another subquery fixed this...

```sql
$merged_post_list = implode(',', $post_id_list);

...

UPDATE " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS p
INNER JOIN (    SELECT p.post_id, p.anonymous_index AS old_index,
                       merged.poster_id, merged.anonymous_index AS new_index
                FROM " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS p,
                (       SELECT poster_id, anonymous_index
                        FROM " . POSTS_TABLE . "
                        WHERE post_id IN ($merged_post_list)
                        AND topic_id = $topic_id
                        AND anonymous_index > 0
                ) AS merged
                WHERE p.post_id NOT IN ($merged_post_list)
                AND p.topic_id = $topic_id
                AND p.anonymous_index > 0
                AND p.poster_id = merged.poster_id
                GROUP BY merged.poster_id
) AS postdata
SET p.anonymous_index = postdata.old_index
WHERE p.topic_id = $topic_id
AND anonymous_index > 0
AND anonymous_index <> postdata.old_index
AND p.poster_id = postdata.poster_id
```

post_id is the primary index, poster_id and topic_id are also indices.

Here's some sample behavior:

Before merge:

```
|post_id_____poster_id_____anonymous_index|
| 11         | 3           | 2            |
| 12         | 22          | 1            |
| 14         | 22          | 1            |
| 15         | 3           | 2            |
```

After merge:

```
|post_id_____poster_id_____anonymous_index|
| 10         | 22          | 4            |
| 11         | 3           | 2            |
| 12         | 22          | 1            |
| 13         | 3           | 4            |
| 14         | 22          | 1            |
| 15         | 3           | 2            |
| 16         | 22          | 4            |
```

After UPDATE (the above query):

```
|post_id_____poster_id_____anonymous_index|
| 10         | 22          | 1            |
| 11         | 3           | 2            |
| 12         | 22          | 1            |
| 13         | 3           | 2            |
| 14         | 22          | 1            |
| 15         | 3           | 2            |
| 16         | 22          | 1            |
```

EDIT:  I've made the following index and an alternative SELECT query to avoid having two subqueries, how would these fare?:
`(topic_id, poster_id, anonymous_index, post_id)`

```sql
SELECT p.post_id, p.anonymous_index AS old_index,
        merged.poster_id, merged.anonymous_index AS new_index
FROM " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS p,
     " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS merged
WHERE p.topic_id = $topic_id
AND p.anonymous_index > 0
AND p.post_id NOT IN ($post_list)
AND p.poster_id = merged.poster_id
AND merged.topic_id = $topic_id
AND merged.anonymous_index > 0
AND merged.post_id IN ($post_list)
GROUP BY merged.poster_id
ORDER BY NULL
```

Comment: i think you are trying to complicate things...

Comment: post your exact problem and we can write a proper query for that without these redundant subqueries...

Comment: I added a new SELECT query to replace the old one inside of the inner join, and I made an index to go along with it.  Also, I thought I did explain the problem pretty clearly.  I even included 3 tables to see the before merge data, after merge broken data, and after fix results.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an inner join update across three self-joins:

```
UPDATE " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS final
INNER JOIN " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS p
  ON p.poster_id = final.poster_id
  AND p.topic_id = final.topic_id
  AND p.topic_id = $topic_id
  AND p.post_id NOT IN ($merged_post_list)
  AND p.anonymous_index > 0
INNER JOIN " . POSTS_TABLE . " AS merged 
  ON merged.poster_id = p.poster_id
  AND merged.topic_id = p.topic_id 
  AND merged.topic_id = $topic_id
  AND merged.post_id IN ($merged_post_list)
  AND merged.anonymous_index > 0

SET final.anonymous_index = p.anonymous_index

WHERE final.anonymous_index > 0
  AND final.anonymous_index <> p.anonymous_index
```

Comment: I edited the OP and added a new SELECT query on the bottom of it.  What about if I made the index:
`(topic_id, poster_id, anonymous_index, post_id)`
and replaced the inner sql query with what I've added to the bottom of the OP?